# Ruby - find_or_intialize_by not assigning attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use find_or_initialize_by however it is not assigning attributes as it should do.. I have the following:

```
vote_id = 1534
vote = record.answer_records.find_or_initialize_by(stage_answer_id: vote_id)
```

When I enter binding.pry I can see the following:

```
vote
=> #<AnswerRecord id: 3926, stage_record_id: 2210, stage_answer_id: nil, value: "{:stage_answer_id=>1563}", correct: false, created_at: "2017-09-06 11:33:49", updated_at: "2017-09-06 11:33:49", deleted_at: nil>
```

For some reason it is assigning

```
value: "{:stage_answer_id=>1563}"
```

rather than

```
stage_answer_id: 1563
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

EDIT: answer_record.rb

```
class AnswerRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_paranoid

  belongs_to :stage_record
  belongs_to :stage_answer
  has_one :activity_feedback

  def self.for_answer(answer)
    find_by(stage_answer: answer)
  end

  def wrong?
    !correct
  end
end
```

SECOND EDIT:
More from byebug:

```
>> opinion
=> #<AnswerRecord id: nil, stage_record_id: nil, stage_answer_id: 1692, value: "This is my answer", correct: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, deleted_at: nil>
>> opinion.save
!! #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "value" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3938, 2222, 1692, null, f, 2017-09-06 12:03:09.851213, 2017-09-06 12:03:09.851213, null).
: INSERT INTO "answer_records" ("stage_answer_id", "stage_record_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id">
```

As the log shows PSQL is trying to update other attributes and not the 'value' attribute, and I don't have any intializers set up..

THIRD EDIT:

```
show-method record.answer_records.find_or_initialize_by
```

returns the following

```
From: /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb @ line 223:
13:15:53 web.1  | Owner: ActiveRecord::Relation
13:15:53 web.1  | Visibility: public
13:15:53 web.1  | Number of lines: 3
13:15:53 web.1  | 
13:15:53 web.1  | def find_or_initialize_by(attributes, &block)
13:15:53 web.1  |   find_by(attributes) || new(attributes, &block)
13:15:53 web.1  | end
```

Comment: Have you overridden the `initialize`method? This is not normal behaviour.

Comment: Not to my knowledge..

Comment: Wait, hang on.. I just noticed something. At the top of your post, you wrote: `AnswerRecord id: 3926`  -- The record **already exists**!! You have **found** it; not initialized it. (So the `value` is *not being assigned*. It was already there.) This is what's caused the confusion.

Comment: As to how/why you managed to create a record with this weird `value`, I don't know.

Comment: That's a very useful spot - still very confused as to the value part, but at least it's a step forward, thanks!

Comment: You must have created a record with this weird `value` somewhere else; either in the rails console or in the codebase. But this record creation is not shown anywhere above, so I can't say anything more than that! The "SECOND EDIT" above appears to be unrelated, *expected* behaviour: you have a database constraint that disallows creating records with a `NULL value`.

Comment: Sure but the second edit shows the object has a value that is not null, and when I try save it it thinks that value is null :(

Comment: Oh, right... Yeah, that's weird. Again, have you shown us the **whole** model?? Do you have any `before_save` hooks, or `before_validation`, or `before_create`, ... that could be affecting this?

Comment: That's literaly the whole model, like 15 lines and inherting directly from ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: Given that the mystery around your original question is now resolved, I would suggest creating a new SO post with a *complete* code sample from your "second edit". How is the record being initialized? What is the `answer_records` database table schema? Do you have any unusual code that's overriding default rails behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand how `find_or_initialize_by` works, looking on code from `show-method` you have to see that it's:

```
 def find_or_initialize_by(attributes, &block)
   find_by(attributes) || new(attributes, &block)
 end
```

so in your case it's like:

```
record.answer_records.find_by(stage_answer_id: vote_id) ||
record.answer_records.new(stage_answer_id: vote_id)
```

I assume that you think that you are calling new, but probably you already have an record with matching `stage_product_id` and `stage_answer_id` so `.new` is never called. And probably that record have that confusing `value` text field.

you may call `.persisted?` method to verify if record is new or from DB, and check DB logs in your console:

```
vote_id = 1534
vote = record.answer_records.find_or_initialize_by(stage_answer_id: vote_id)
puts vote.persisted?
```

*It worth noting that @tom-lord came up with answer in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074213/ruby-find-or-intialize-by-not-assigning-attributes/46075453?noredirect=1#comment79111665_46074213) a few moments before me*

Comment: Why would you not just edit your answer? This did not offer an alternate solution to the original answer since neither one of them really "answered" the question but rather just pointed at potential issues.

Comment: I think about deleting first answer as it's not answering exact question and has too much noise

Comment: If you believe that to be true then delete it otherwise the combination of these 2 answers is "creating too much noise" in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through it all Dmitriy - genuinely appreciated random stranger!!